# Install ProxMox AND cPanel

Tags: linux, virtualization, web-server, kvm-virtualization

I'm in the process of upgrading our server to something much larger.

This new server has CentOS and cPanel/WHM installed by default. My question is, is it possible to install a VM solution like Virtuozzo or ProxMox and still have it work with cPanel?

Forgive the noob question :(

Comment: What is your definition of "works with". Why do you need cPanel in the first place? It sounds like you are probably trying to have this server fulfill many different roles...

Comment: Yes. I'd love to have it fulfill many different roles. I'd like to have this server be a main webserver that can handle different clients hence the cPanel, but also would like to have ProxMox to offer VPS's of a nature.

Answer (score 1):

If you need cPanel for web hosting management and would like to use PVE for VPSes, the route to go would be

- install and configure PVE (you would have to replace your current CentOS installation as PVE is an own, modified Distro)
- create a virtual machine within PVE
- install the distro of your choice within this virtual machine
- complete the network configuration
- install cPanel within the virtual machine

Although it would be technically possible to run cPanel on the physical host within the PVE install, it would create supportability problems which would be especially visible with updates / upgrades of PVE.